# How do I change a color from an image that corresponds to a different image?

Tags: java, image, loops, colors, rgb

So I would like to ask how would I be able to change the color of one image that corresponds to a different image.

For example

From this image, [First Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqzUq.jpg)

From the red line down, With the exact same color, I would completely like to recolor this image corresponding to the color scale from the first image, so [Second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMKRI.jpg)

From the same color scale that I used In the First Image, so I would only be able to keep the colors in the second image above the the red line in the colors from the first image.

I already have this code to over write the image as different colors.

```
public void createOutImmage(){
    imgout = new BufferedImage(imwidth, imheight, 1);
     for (int ix = 0; ix < imwidth; ix++){
         for (int iy = 0; iy < imheight; iy++){
             int rbval = img.getRGB(ix, iy);
             double hei = getHeight(rbval);
             if(hei > 50){
                 imgout.setRGB(ix, iy, rbval);
             }
             else {
```

I have already assigned the Each color on the scale to a different height value

```
/*
 *  Getting  height from coded color (RGB)
 * 
 */
public double getHeight(int rgb){
    double hx =0.; 
    Color tcol = new Color(rgb);
    int ered =  tcol.getRed();
    int eblue =  tcol.getBlue();
    int egreen =  tcol.getGreen(); 
    if( ered > 248){    // range 180 -390 
        hx = 180.+210.*(258-(double)egreen)/255.; 
        return hx;
    }
    if(ered <= 248 && ered > 7){ //range  81 -180
        hx = 81.+ 99 * ((double)ered/250.);
    }
    if( ered <= 7 ){
      if(egreen >= 249 ) // using blue  value to calculate height
                         // range 23 -81
      {
         hx = 23. + 58. *((double)255 - eblue)/255.;


      }
      else               //using green to calculate height
      {

        hx =   24.* ((double)egreen-20.)/230.; 

      }


    }


    return hx;
}
```

}

And the "if(hei > 50){" as the "hei" is the corresponding height for the colors as I could change that value so any color height below that value will automatically change to a purple color to simulate the sea rising etc.